# Jenkinsfile pipeline running PS1 script from git

Tags: powershell, jenkins-pipeline

Am really struggling with this and the only examples I can seem to find are for cmdlets to be run not scripts cloned from a Git repo.  I have the following:

pipeline {

```
environment {
        JOB_BASE_NAME="org-onprem-2016"
        VERSION="$BUILD_NUMBER"
        teamsColorRed="C50E2E"
        teamsColorGreen="7FBA00"
}
// Helper function to run PowerShell Commands

agent {
    node {
        label 'Windows'
    }
}

stages {
    stage('Checkout SCM') {
        steps {
        step([$class: 'WsCleanup'])
            dir ('inv_onprem_2016') {
            git url: 'https://github.local/org-cit/org_onprem_2016.git', credentialsId: 'svc-tokenauth'
            }
        }
    }
    stage('Initiate Build Variables') {
        steps {
            powerShell('scripts\\2012\\initiatevars.ps1')
            }
    }
```

I have tried multiple iterations over the steps bit but always get some form of error around path not found etc.  I think I am missing how the workspace should be addressed but tried $ENV:WORKSPACE in front and got the same result (different error around no "ENV" being defined).  Can anyone help steer me in the right direction for this?

Comment: Such paths are always relative to the jenkins workspace. Is your script located there or somewhere else in the filesystem?

Comment: it is in the workspace as far as I know as I am cloning the repo at each run

Comment: Can you add the workspace directory structure maybe? This would help a lot

Comment: ah being relative makes sense.  the "dir" entry in the checkout stage was adding an extra directory layer to the path i had not expected.  thanks

Comment: Yes, exactly. The dir set you to the directory workspace/inv_... so relative to the workspace.